# Trigonometric function graph

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to tweak a trigonometric function in Wolframalpha to kinda transform the sin function into a rounded square function. Please see screenshot here: [Wolframaplpha graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFpMS.png).

First function looks good for y=1, but I'd prefer to have a higher slope for y=0, just as the second function is.

Is there an elegant formula to achieve that with a periodic function , like sin?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Fourier synthesis of an unnormalized square wave, cut off at term $n$.  Adjust $n$ to your needs.

$f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1, 3, 5 \ldots}^n {1 \over i} \sin (i x)$

[image: unnormalized rounded square]

Comment: I am using the function to simulate the air bubble movement in an Android "level" app. Your response is great, but the amplitude of the horizontal part makes the air bubble wobble noticeably. Is there another way to stretch the horizontal part of the sin(sin(x)*1.8) graph?

Answer (score 0):

A Fourier series will work here, it is a linear combination of individual sin functions with different periods and amplitudes. For example, for the square function

$$
f(x) = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2 k + 1}\sin\left((2k + 1)\frac{x}{2}\right)
$$

If you truncate the series at a given $k$ you will be successively better approximations, here's a graph

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. First, I was thinking why is 1.8 so special, but realized it is close to pi/2, so I've changed 1.8 to pi/2. Then, I thought I should try sin(sin(sin(x)...

Here's the graph:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin(sin(x)*pi%2F2)+plot+sin(sin(sin(x)*pi%2F2)*pi%2F2)